# Python: Determining if i have a 16bit encoded string

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I have a UTF-16-BE encoded string:

```
utf16be = '\x0623\x0631\x0646\x0628'

print repr(utf16be)
> '\x0623\x0631\x0646\x0628'
```

I need to know if it's a 1-byte or 2-byte encoding, i have tried with the below snippet:

```
for c in utf16be:
    c_ord = ord(c)
    if c_ord >= 256:
        print 'Its a 2-byte (or more) encoded string'
        break
```

But that wont work because i thought utf16be[0] will be equal to '\x0623', but it's actually equal to '\x06':

```
for c in utf16be:
    print repr(c)

> '\x06'
> '2'
> '3'
> '\x06'
> '3'
> '1'
> '\x06'
> '4'
> '6'
> '\x06'
> '2'
> '8'
```

So what is the best practice to check if i have a 2-byte encoded string ?

Comment: you cannot ... you need to know in advance ... as "\x0034" will treat it as "\x00" + "3" + "4" ... how would you know that thats not that?

Comment: Ideally, you'd know because something, somewhere told you the encoding. Otherwise, the best you can do is try to decode it with various encodings and see if they work.

Comment: I have written an utf16be string for the sake of simplicity, but in real env. i would get any string as input and i must know about its byte encoding (1, 2 or more bytes per char)

Comment: "I have written an utf16be string" - no, you haven't. You tried, but what you have is something else entirely. If you want an example string encoded the way you want, `encode` a Unicode string.

Comment: \x0623 is an UTF16 character i picked up from UTF16 table, why shall i write it in unicode and then encode it to UTF16 when i can get directly in the latter ?

Comment: so you can see what a utf16 encoded string looks like in python maybe?

Answer (score 1):

A UTF-16-BE encoded string necessarily has two bytes per code unit (hence the name 16 bits). UTF-8 has single bytes but UTF-16 does not.

Your comment suggests you're getting a string and you need to figure out whether it's one, two or more bytes per character but that doesn't make sense. You need to know the encoding of the string to make sense of it - otherwise it's guesswork.

Comment: repr(utf16be) is returning what i'm looking for, it knows that it's a 2 byte encoding since it's returning \x0623 and not \x06\x23, so how it's done ?

Comment: it does not ... its returning `"\x06" + "\x32"+"\x33"` (or `"\x06" + "2" + "3"`) ... additionally if you dont know the encoding who are you to say thats not the correct interpretation (you do know in this case __because you know the encoding__)  a string that is "\x06\x23" would actually be the 16 bits ... "\x0623" is 24 bits ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [chardet package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to guess encoding

Comment: Am not about to detect encoding, i need to know if its 1, 2 or more bytes per char encoding, no matter if it's UTF-16-BE or KANJI_JIS ...

Comment: all you can do is guess